# NOT search for one to many core data relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a one to many relationship, relationship "people", from my main entity to another entity, entity "People", with a list of people, attribution "person".  I am trying to do a search with a fetchedResultsController for all the main entities where a particular "person" does not have a relationship "people".  I have tried using this predicate search strings:

```
@"(NOT ('%@' IN[cd] people.person))", notPersonSearch

@"(NOT (ANY people.person == '%@'))", notPersonSearch
```

They both sort of work.  If only one "person" has a relationship to the main entity than that particular entity is excluded from the search results.  However if there are more than one "person" with a relationship to the main entity that entity is included in the results even if the excluded name is one of the "person" attributes.

First is there a better way to write this predicate?  If not can I run a second search for entities that match the notPersonSearch and compare them with all the results and keep the results that are not common to both searches?

Comment: Those predicates don't make sense to me. Can you post a sample of the entities involved here?

Comment: I have tried to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for `@"NONE people.person == %@", notPersonSearch`

See: [Aggregate Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) in the Predicate Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it produce the same results as the predicate about.